# Integrals of matrix functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, matrices, reference-request, integration

I've stumbled across some math I've never really encountered before, and I would love it if someone could provide me with some useful references and texts on it. I'm dealing with integration over the space of matrices, as in Random Matrix Theory and such. Specifically, I think I've narrowed my confusion down to two different types of matrix integration, some of the form 
\begin{equation}G=\int dA \,f(A)\end{equation} Where $A$ is a matrix of some sort, and $f(A)$ is also a matrix. Then there are integrals of the form 
\begin{equation}H=\int dA \,f(|A|)\end{equation} Where $|A|$ is the determinant. This also includes integrals involving $\mathrm{tr}(A)$, i.e., integrals of scalar functions of matrices. Essentially, integrals of matrix functions of matrices, and integrals of scalar functions of matrices over some measure of matrices.

Also, is there any good literature on extensions of contour integration and complex analysis to these sorts of matrix functions?

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what's the context and definition of your first equation, maybe you can give a reference for the occurrence of that form.

For the second you might look into the definition of a Haar measure/integral. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure. The construction of the Haar measure is for example given in chapter 10 of Folland, Real Analysis. On Wikipedia you'll see the explicit form for GL(n,R).

For random matrices you can see examples for measures on the Gaussian unitary esemble (GUE) or Gaussion orthogonal ensemble (GOE) in the  wikipedia article on random matrices http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix. This article has a lot of references with a guide to it.

Concerning your question about contour integration I vaguely remember that I learned it a bit more general for operators from Dunford/Schwartz Linear Operators.

Hope it helps.